# ddos for server congestion using OMNeT++

Tags: server, omnet++, ddos

I am currently try to develop a ddos model to crease congestion at server ( using standardHost ) in OMNeT++. Can anyone tell me how to develop one ? I would like to create congestion at server , not the communication link.

Answer (score 0):

Default models, applications in the INET framework do NOT model the CPU resource constraint of a node. (i.e. They assume that the server has infinite number of CPUs to process the requests). Also resource requirements for packet processing (apart from memory buffers) are not modeled either. You have to write your own components and add them to INET at the right places. i.e. out of box, INET is not suitable to model that kind of problem (however you can add your own models to it.)

Comment: thanks. yes. think got to do in this methods. Other way might be using simple model to create each simple network with the entry point using router. So every simple module ( a network ) link up create a multiple network communicate. Then only select a victim host to launch the ddos. I am trying this.